# How can I implement multiple UIPickerView in a single page?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am implementing `UIPickerView` in a text field as below:

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return states.count // states is an array of strings
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return states[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField.text = states[row]
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

I want to have another textfield that implement `UIPickerView`. How should I do it? Can I alter the methods implemented above to include both text fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily you can set to each pickerView a tag value, for example:

```
let firstPV = UIPickerView()
pickerV.tag = 1

let secondPV = UIPickerView()
secondPV.tag = 2
```

In this way, just you have to evaluate the tag property in the PickerView' protocols, like:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    switch pickerView.tag {
        case 1:
            return 1
        case 2:
            return 3
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```